# How to convert rgba(92, 184, 92, 1) to the color name?

Tags: java, css, selenium, colors

I have written the below code which is returning the color code like `rgba(92, 184, 92, 1)`.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userDetails-active")).getCssValue("background-color");

System.out.println(Color.fromString(s).asHex())
```

How to convert `rgba(92, 184, 92, 1)` to the corresponding color name using Java?

Comment: Not all colors have a name. Are you sure this one does?

Comment: Wait, are you using Java or JavaScript? Those are different languages.

Comment: yes this color should return green

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say not all codes have a human readable name. However, there's this [util](https://gist.github.com/XiaoxiaoLi/8031146) class

What it does is keeps a map of all the existing human readable names, and maps the code to the closest one. See if it suits your needs